# docopt doesn't apply default value

Tags: python, command-line-interface, docopt

I have the following usage string:

```
    usage = """Usage: 
    counts_editing_precent_total_editing_to_csv.py out <output> files <pileupPercentFiles>... [--percentageField=<kn>] [--numReadsField=<kn>]
    counts_editing_precent_total_editing_to_csv.py -h | --help

Options:
     -h --help  show this screen.
     --percentageField=<kn>  the column of the percent field in the input file  [default: 7] .
     --numReadsField=<kn>  the column of the num of reads field in the input file  [default: 4] .

    """
```

and then I execute this code

```
    args = docopt(usage)
    print(args)
```

I run the following command:

```
python <filename>.py out a files a b c
```

The output is:

```
{'--help': False,
 '--numReadsField': None,
 '--percentageField': None,
 '-h': False,
 '<output>': 'a',
 '<pileupPercentFiles>': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 'files': True,
 'out': True}
```

As you can see, the default values aren't used.
I have seen other questions like this where the solution was 'Have two spaces between the command and it's description' and I made sure that I have.
I really can't tell the difference from my example to the one which appears in the [docs](http://try.docopt.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran it and it works. Recall that you should place the usage string before the `from docopt import docopt` at the top of the file. Here is a script to reproduce it.

```
"""Usage:
    counts_editing_precent_total_editing_to_csv.py out <output> files <pileupPercentFiles>... [--percentageField=<kn>] [--numReadsField=<kn>]
    counts_editing_precent_total_editing_to_csv.py -h | --help

Options:
     -h --help  show this screen.
     --percentageField=<kn>  the column of the percent field in the input file  [default: 7] .
     --numReadsField=<kn>  the column of the num of reads field in the input file  [default: 4] .

"""
from docopt import docopt
ARGUMENTS = docopt(__doc__)
print(ARGUMENTS)
```

Comment: Honestly, I forgot about that it should be on the top of the file but even after changing it, it produces the same dictionary

Comment: Can you provide your code? Or run the one I provided?

Comment: There shouldn't be a "usage=" for example as in your question

Comment: There was a difference between our strings, I ran ```diff``` and got this:  
```
1c1
< """Usage: 
---
> """Usage:
10c10
<     """
---
> """
```